# Python 2.7: xbee module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbee

I have installed the modules to control xbee with Python (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee). Afterwards I have set the path variable on `C:\Python27\python-xbee-master` and also the subdirectories. To check, if the modules are available, I have written the code as recommended (see also link above):

```
# Import and init xbee device
from xbee import XBee
import serial
import arduino
```

The interpreter gave the error message:

```
File "C:/Users/daniel/PycharmProjects/hardware_test/test_xbee.py", line 2, in <module>
from xbee import XBee
ImportError: No module named xbee
```

I have done the same with https://github.com/nioinnovation/python-xbee and it have the same effect.
As I'm not very familiar with Python, I would like to know, what is going wrong and how I can find the module.

Comment: You installed it wrong. It looks like you tried to do it by hand. Get pip. Use pip to install things.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: install with: `pip install xbee`